# My app icon has changed back to Android default after updating Android OS

Tags: android-studio, android-manifest, android-icons

I was prompted with an Android update today which I agreed to and after it had run and rebooted the app I've been working on has gone back to the Android default icon. The text is correct but even after uninstalling the app and re-installing it the default icon remains. I've checked the Android manifest and the settings remain the same as below

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

I've checked the files and they are the same, so why does my app still show the Android icon? Has anyone else experienced this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did had similar problem, what i did is replaced my logo file with standard resolutions framed by google [Here](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html#foreground.type=clipart&foreground.clipart=android&foreground.space.trim=1&foreground.space.pad=0.25&foreColor=rgba(96%2C%20125%2C%20139%2C%200)&backColor=rgb(68%2C%20138%2C%20255)&crop=0&backgroundShape=square&effects=none&name=ic_launcher)
with exiting one in the project. As your exiting logo might not following the new and updated standards of Android.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I used the link you gave me to replace the images ic_launcher and ic_launcher_round in the mimap folders in my res folder. I deleted the original app and re-installed but the Android logo  is still there. I have one other image called ic_launcher-web.png which is unchanged but I don't think that has anything to do with this. Is there anything I might have missed?

Comment: @user616076 Did you find a solution? I noticed that this happens on a handful of devices. Not all of them.